# Why apache2 module can't be removed?

Tags: apache-2.4

```
sudo apt purge apache2
sudo apt remove apache2
sudo apt autoremove
```

To check if something related apache2 still remain in my os.

```
sudo find /  -name  'apache*'
/usr/lib/apache2
ls /usr/lib/apache2/modules
httpd.exp             mod_authnz_ldap.so      mod_cgid.so          mod_file_cache.so           mod_lua.so             mod_proxy_http2.so     mod_slotmem_plain.so
libphp7.0.so          mod_authz_core.so       mod_cgi.so           mod_filter.so               mod_macro.so           mod_proxy_http.so      mod_slotmem_shm.so
mod_access_compat.so  mod_authz_dbd.so        mod_charset_lite.so  mod_headers.so              mod_mime_magic.so      mod_proxy_scgi.so      mod_socache_dbm.so
mod_actions.so
```

Why so many apache2's module can't be removed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you only removed the package `apache2` and not all related packages.

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so
apache2-bin: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_access_compat.so
```

`mod_access_compat.so` is in `apache2-bin`. the php module obviously is from PHP.

Use `dpkg -S` to check what packages the files come from.